# Dynamic Value in SOQL LIKE

Tags: apex, trigger, soql

I am trying to fetch record in my trigger using SOQL using LIKE. 
The value I need to compare is a combination of three fields.
I am trying the below code. Not sure what I am doing wrong

```
string DocName = ''+q.SBQQ__Account__c+' - '+q.SBQQ__Account__c+' - '+q.Name+'%';
Document d = [Select id from Document where Name LIKE ''+DocName+'' order by CreatedDate asc LIMIT 1];
```

Comment: what is the error? p.s. there are a lot of questions on dynamic SOQL - this is most likely to be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @SantanuBoral Not exactly, the string I want to compare is a combination of the three fields. For example my string to compare would be Account - Account - Name

Answer (score 2):

This query isn't even dynamic SOQL. You just use **[*bind* syntax](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_variables.htm)**:

```
WHERE Name LIKE :docName
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope your looking for this

```
string DocName ='\'' + q.SBQQ__Account__c +' - '+ q.SBQQ__Account__c + ' - '+ q.Name+'%\'';
Document d = [Select id from Document where Name LIKE :DocName order by CreatedDate asc LIMIT 1];
```